# How to make expandable recycler view like imgur comment section

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

I want to make expandable recycler view with dynamic no of item. I need same recycler view as imagur comment section for each image. How to add that dynamic no of childern view in row of recyclerview.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I asked similar question but no one answer so i searched and find a way.
you can define a layout for your view and inflate it programmatically.
it's not against preferences in Android. So inflate your layout using LayoutInflater :

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View inflatedLayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, null, false);
    yourParentView.addView(inflatedLayout);
```

"yourParentView" is the Relative or Linear Layout. don't forget to add this LayoutInflater in your "onBindViewHolder". hope this work.